# How to get hyperlinked text

Tags: c#, itext

I have some code that gets the url of a hyperlink in a pdf document:

```
                for (int i = 1; i <= document.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                var page = document.GetPage(i);
                IList<PdfAnnotation> annots = page.GetAnnotations();
                if ((annots != null) && (annots.Count != 0))
                {
                    foreach (PdfAnnotation annot in annots)
                    {
                        if (annot.GetSubtype().Equals(PdfName.Link))
                        {
                            PdfDictionary annotAction =
                                ((PdfLinkAnnotation)annot).GetAction();
                            if (annotAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI))
                            {
                                PdfString uri = annotAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URI);
                                string uriStr = uri.ToString();
                                string titleStr;
                                PdfString title = annot.GetTitle();
                                if (title != null)
                                   titleStr = title.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code is good at forming the address of the hyperlink - uriStr. I need to get not only the address of the hyperlink, but also the text that the hyperlink is superimposed on. PdfString statement title = annot.GetTitle (); produces title null. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks tbc and mkl for the good ideas.

Added the following code:

```
PdfString contents = annot.GetContents(); 
if (contents != null) 
   string contentsStr = contents.ToString();
```

contents always equal null

I'm trying the second option. I understand how to get the annotation area of a link:

```
PdfArray rectArray = annot.GetRectangle();
```

but don't understand how to extract text from this area.

I figured out how to do it.

Comment: try getContents() https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.2/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/annot/PdfAnnotation.html#getContents--

Comment: *"the text that the hyperlink is superimposed on"* - you get that by taking the area of the link annotation and applying text extraction to that area of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of this algorithm. Perhaps it will be useful to someone. I used the code at C# iText7 text coordinate extraction question to extract the document test and character coordinates
[C# iText7 text coordinate extraction question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887347/c-sharp-itext7-text-coordinate-extraction-question). I modified the code a little. Commented out the lines of code

```
//if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.GetText()))
//   continue;
```

and changed the lines of code

```
var letterStart = t.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
var letterEnd = t.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
```

to

```
var letterStart = t.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
var letterEnd = t.GetBaseline().GetEndPoint();
```

As a result, I get an array of characters and their coordinates for each page. For each link on the page, I get the region in which it is located.

```
PdfArray rectArray = annot.GetRectangle();
```

And further in the array of symbols I find those symbols that are included in this area.

```
double x1 = ((PdfNumber)rectArray.Get(0)).GetValue();
double y1 = ((PdfNumber)rectArray.Get(1)).GetValue();
double x2 = ((PdfNumber)rectArray.Get(2)).GetValue();
double y2 = ((PdfNumber)rectArray.Get(3)).GetValue();
// the text that the hyperlink is superimposed on
string fragment = ""; 
for (int i = 0; i < textRects.Count; i++)
{
   if (textRects[i].x1 >= x1 && textRects[i].x2 <= x2 &&
       textRects[i].y1 >= y1 && textRects[i].y2 <= y2)
     fragment += textRects[i].text;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Please be aware that the annotation **Rect**angle may be too large, the correct area is given by the **QuadPoints** and only defaults to the **Rect**angle. In particular in case of links broken over two or more lines, the actually active link area given by the **QuadPoints** may be smaller than the encompassing **Rect**angle.